# Can salt-water frogs survive in normal water (A well)?

Tags: zoology, salt

I don't know much about frogs, but there seem to be salt water frogs.

1) Are there such things as salt water frogs?

2) Are there frogs that live in the sea? (in reference to Vivekananda's quote)

3) Can salt water frogs survive in well water or fresh water?

> Well, one day another frog that lived in the sea came and fell into the well. - Vivekananda

Comment: There are no salt water frogs. There is [only one species](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crab-eating_frog) which lives in mangrove swamps and is perhaps the only amphibian that can tolerate salinity.

Comment: There's a bit more detail on the crab-eating frog here: http://www.biodiversityscience.com/2011/04/27/saltwater-frogs-water-conservation/

Comment: @WYSIWYG So, was Vivekananda's quote "A frog that lived in the sea" scientifically wrong. Also see the updated Q.

Comment: @Wally He must have meant it metaphorically.

Comment: He also mocked evolution so.. http://www.swamivivekanandaquotes.org/2014/04/swami-vivekanandas-frog-in-well-story.html

Comment: "A frog lived in a well. It had lived there for a long time. It was born there and brought up there, and yet was a little, small frog. Of course the evolutionists were not there then to tell us whether the frog lost its eyes or not," - Vivekananda

Comment: frogs are a pretty specialized/derived group in amphibians anyway so it is not surprising they are fresh water only, there are saline living salamanders though, well one species anyway, Ambystoma taylori.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to Wikipedia the Crab-eating frog is the only amphibian that can survive in sea water. However Wikipedia also suggests that it can only survive `brief excursions into the sea`.

There are no such things as sea frogs.

Even the Crab-eating frog doesn't live in the sea though. Its natural habitat is mangrove swamps.

> The crab-eating frog (*Fejervarya cancrivora*), is a frog native to south-eastern Asia including Taiwan, China, the Philippines and more rarely as far west as Orissa in India. It inhabits mangrove swamps and marshes and is the only known modern amphibian which can tolerate brief excursions into sea water.
>
> This frog can tolerate marine environments (immersion in sea water for brief periods or brackish water for extended periods) by increasing urea production and retention, and by remaining slightly hyperosmotic within urea and sodium flux. Adults can survive in salt water with salinity as high as 2.8%, and tadpoles can survive salinities as high as 3.9%.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crab-eating_frog